# e10s: Embedding XUL in HTML by iframe

Tags: html, firefox, iframe, xul

I am a Firefox extension developer and expirence troubles with e10s feature.
When e10s is enabled in Firefox I can't embed .xul page in extension html page by IFRAME, I am getting blank frame.

```
<iframe src="chrome://addon/page.xul" type="chrome"></iframe>
```

Result:

[image]

I also try to register about: url for this page, but it doesn't help, I am getting message that URL is incorrect.

```
<iframe src="about:myaddon" type="chrome"></iframe>
```

about:myaddon works properly when opened directly in tab.

[image]

There is any way to embed XUL into HTML by IFRAME when e10 is activated?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know XUL is only allowed to run in the parent (chrome) process. So the HTML page itself in which you're embedding the XUL iframe also has to run in chrome, i.e. the containing `<xul:browser>` or `<xul:iframe>` has to be flagged non-remote and probably chrome-privileged.

Answer (score 0):

There was а problem with multiprocessor shims in firefox, guys from Mozilla fixed this issue, and "about:" urls works fine now.